# Check if a Integer is empty

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to check if a `Integer` value is empty.
The value for `Integer` is completed in a form. Here is my code.

Here the value is introduced:

```
<input name="varsta" placeHolder="Varsta:" type="text" data-constraints='@NotEmpty @Required @AlphaSpecial'> <br/><br/>
```

Now I want to check if there are data introduced or not.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Integer varsta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("varsta"));
    request.getSession().setAttribute("varsta", varsta);

    try {
        DBConnection connection = new DBConnection();
        Connection con = connection.Connect();

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "insert into user(Nume,Prenume,E_mail,Parola,Varsta,Sex,Greutate,Inaltime,Nivel_activitate,Calcul_calorii)" + 
            "values ('"+nume+"','"+prenume+"','"+email1+"','"+parola+"','"+varsta+"','"+sex+"','"+greutate+"','"+inaltime+"','"+activitate+"','"+calorii+"')"
        );

        if (varsta == null && "".equals(varsta)) {
            String message = "Va rugam completati cu atentie TOATE campurile!";
            request.setAttribute("message", message);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/inregistrare.jsp").forward(request, response);           
        } else {
           int i = ps.executeUpdate();

           if (i > 0) {
              request.getRequestDispatcher("/preferinte.jsp").forward(request, response);
           }
        }
        ps.close();
        con.close();         
    } catch(Exception se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

is not working.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: There are some errors and misconceptions in your code. What does `System.out.println(request.getParameter("varsta"))` prints? Some of the errors: You defined you variable as `varsta` and you are checking `Varsta` this is just the first problem. Being `varsta` an Integer you can't check it against "" (empty) it is an Integer.

Comment: Did you mean `varsta` reference instead of `Varsta` in you `if`-condition? If you did, this `if`-statement will never return `true`, since you're comparing different types of objects: `Integer` against `String`

Comment: What is `request`?

Comment: Was a mistake when I wrote "Varsta", is it 'varsta'. I know that is an integer and I check for String....That is the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class `Integer` is just an wrapper on top of primitive `int` type. So it can either be `null` or store a valid integer value. There is no obvious "empty" definition for it.

If you just compare `Integer` against empty `String`, you''ll get `false` as a result. Always. See `Integer.equals(Object o)` implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**First of all, you can get a `NumberFormatException` during parsing integer in the line:**

```
Integer varsta = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("varsta"));
```

**And you are getting it, since `For input string: ""` looks like a `NumberFormatExpection` message.**

In your example you should either check whether the `"varsta"` attribute value is a number (assume it's a string) and then parse it, or parse it as is and catch `NumberFormatException` that `Integer.parseInt()` throws on incorrect argument.

**First solution:**

```
Integer varsta = null;
String varstaStr = request.getParameter("varsta"); // read string 'varsta' field
if (varstaStr != null && varstaStr.matches("\\d+")) { // null-check and regex check to make sure the string contains only digits
     varsta = Integer.parseInt(varstaStr);
}
```

**Second solution:**

```
Integer varsta = null;
String varstaStr = request.getParameter("varsta"); // read string 'varsta' field
try {
    varsta = Integer.parseInt(varsta);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

**After this, you have one more problem in the line:**

```
if(varsta == null && "".equals(varsta)){
```

The `varsta` reference has type `Integer` here, so `"".equals(varsta)` will always return `false`:

```
(varsta == null && "".equals(varsta)) = [assume varsta is null] =
((null) == null && "".equals(null)) = (true && false) = false
```

Replace

```
if(varsta == null && "".equals(varsta)){
```

with

```
if(varsta == null){
```

This should help you.

**P.S.** If you use Java of version 7 or higher, consider use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to manage `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: I want only to check if in the  field that represent value is  empty/null or not. If Yes returns me a message If no returns me another message.

The problem is that 'varsta' in int but i check it as a string. 
I don't know how to check it like integer

Comment: @Bogdan if you need to check whether a `String` instance is `null` or empty, you can just use `str != null && !"".equals(str)` condition. You can also use `String.isNotEmpty(String str)` from [Apache commong-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) or `String.isNotBlank(String str)` if you wanna exclude blank strings as well

Comment: using:   if (varsta == null && "".equals(varsta) ) seems not to work.
HTTP Status 500 - For input string: ""

Comment: @Bogdan what type does `request.getParameter("varsta")` return? Does it return `String`, `Integer`, `Object` or anything else? it it returns `String`, see my comment above. If it returns `Integer`, just use simple null-check: `varsta != null`. If it returns other object, let us know what is the type of it

Comment: @Bogdan if `varsta == null` holds, then `"".equals(varsta)` will always return `false`, so you statement won't be executed if `varsta` is `null`.

Comment: Just updated my question.Please take a look? Also in the field varsta I am not introducing nothing. Want to check if it is empty/null/nothing introduced.

Comment: Tried before and now.Not working. HTTP Status 500 - For input string: ""

Comment: @Bogdan, I see. You have 2 issues in our code: parsing integer and condition that check the parsed value. Now you're getting error during parsing integer. I've updated the answer again. You'd better post the stack trace next time, it helps a lot to localize the issue.

Comment: Sorry! I don't see where you've updated your code. What should I write in my if statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117544/discussion-between-vladimir-vagaytsev-and-bogdan).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if your field is empty or not than you can use that:

```
if (!request.getParameter("varsta").equals("")) {
    System.out.println("not empty");
} else {
    System.out.println("Empty");
}
```

But if you want to get the value so you should to be carful:

```
try {
    if (!request.getParameter("varsta").equals("")) {
        System.out.println("not empty");
        Integer varsta = new Integer(request.getParameter("varsta"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exmpty");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Number is not correct");
}
```

what if `request.getParameter("varsta") = "4558ez"`? this can make a problem.

Comment: Catching `Exception` like that is rather... nasty. Better not do it even in some example code. Just catch the relevant exceptions, so `NumberFormatException`, and whatever `request.getParameter` may throw (if you really need to catch anything at all, instead of just letting exceptions to propagate higher).

Comment: using request.getParameter("varsta").equals("") not working.
Error: HTTP Status 500 - For input string: ""